# Two circles touching internally at O. A straigh line cuts these circles at A, B, C and D respectively. Prove that AB: CD = (OA × OB): (OC × OD).

Tags: geometry, circles

S1 and S2 are two circles touching internally at 0, with S₂ being the inner circle. A straigh line cuts S1 at A, D and S₂ at B, C. Prove that AB: CD = (OA × OB): (OC × OD).

My work: I found that angles AOB and COD are equal. So i tried to use trigonometry ( cosine rule ) but did not get any useful result. I also used Pythagoras theorem and found values of AO, BO, CO, and DO with respect to the perpendicular OY drawn on the line but it just became more complicated. There is something that i am missing. So please provide any hint or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the law of sines we get:
$$
{DC\over\sin\angle COD}={OC\over\sin\angle ODA}
\quad\text{and}\quad
{AB\over\sin\angle AOB}={OB\over\sin\angle OAD}.
$$
Dividing the second equality by the first one, and taking into account that $\angle AOB=\angle COD$, we obtain:
$$
{AB\over CD}={OB\over OC}\cdot{\sin\angle ODA\over\sin\angle OAD}.
$$
But the sine of an inscribed angle is equal to the ratio between the subtended chord and the diameter:
$$
\sin\angle ODA={OA\over2r}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sin\angle OAD={OD\over2r}.
$$
Inserting these into the above equality we can then complete the proof.